# Using a FAB to open the camera?

Tags: android, camera, floating-action-button

I am completely new to coding, so please be as clear as possible and I'm going to try and include everything needed, but if you need more code please ask!

I'm trying to get a FAB to open the camera when tapped and save the pictures taken to the camera roll on the phone. I thought this would be simple, but I'm struggling. I've managed to Frankenstein this code together and finally got any errors out of the way at least, but nothing happens when you tap the FAB. I also have two FABs showing up, one right beneath the other and partially hidden, and I'm not sure why. I do have the FAB in a tabbed activity, so maybe that is messing it up?

Java for the tab:

```
package org.gpnc.gpncscavengerhunt;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class hunt1tab1 extends Fragment {


    public hunt1tab1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hunt1tab1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));
                ;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant xml for the same tab (there's also some text and a picture):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.956"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

[Here's a screenshot if that helps explain what I'm seeing as far as two FABs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqoUw.png)

Thank you so much! I've already searched around here to try and find an answer (which is how I got the app running again after I broke it the first few times) but couldn't find anything for exactly what I want (at least that I could understand).

EDIT: I also have these two permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your onClick method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);
```

And add this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: So simply:

`FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivity(intent);` ?

While I don't get any errors this way, it still isn't working. :/ I already had the permission added too (though worded as the other commenter below had it, does that matter?). Sorry the code is hard to read, can't get it to format pretty.

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple FAB issue, I'd guess you actually have two of them in your layouts. There are at least two layouts involved here: your fragment and the activity that hosts it. If each of them has a FAB, then they'll both show up when that activity loads that fragment. Perhaps the FAB you've got the click listener set up on is the one in back and hence, you're unable to click it without clicking the front one?

Hopefully getting rid of the second FAB fixes your click listener issue. If it doesn't, let me know and we'll think about other potential causes. Aside from that, here are a few more considerations:

1. Make sure you have the following under the top level `manifest` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file (see these [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)). It tells Android that your app will make use of the camera and that camera functionality needs to be present on the device in order for your app to work:

   `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />`
2. You're going to want to call `startActivityForResult(...)`, not `startActivity(...)`. That will ensure that the fragment/activity you're calling from will have its `onActivityResult(...)` method called with info about the picture the camera captured.

Comment: Sure enough, there was a second FAB code hiding! I swear I checked that, but oh well. I did at least have that permission already in the manifest so that's one thing I did correctly! The FAB is still not working however.

As far as your second point, I just want to take the picture and have it save to the phone itself in the Camera Roll. Do I still need startActivityForResult? I get an error when I add it in. A lot of walkthroughs that I found had the app display the image above the button after taking it, which I don't want.